# Google Maps API JS - Accessing a Markers Location from another JS file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, global

I need to use the location a marker is placed to be able to load weather data via another API. I have my map dropping a loading and dropping a marker as well as a object "myPosition" which *should* contain the lat and lon of the marker. My issue is getting the myPosition.lat and .lng to update with the coordinates of the marker. Below is the code I have thus far and I am able to get the initialized data from myPosition in another file but I cant figure out how to get the coordinates. This is my first time using HTML and JS and I usually use C++ or Java so its a bit of a change for me.

```
var myPosition = 
{
lat: 0,
lng: 0
}; 

function initMap()
{
var texas = {lat: 32.7767, lng: -96.7970};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
{
    zoom: 10,
    center: texas
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: texas,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
{
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location)
{ 
    if (marker == undefined)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: location,
            map: map, 
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });
    }
    else
    {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }

map.setCenter(location);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. myPosition is defined and not used. I read your question twice and it's still not clear what you're asking. It might be a language issue but please try to clarify. What do you mean 'another file'?

Comment: I have another js file "weather.js" which I want to use "myPosition". The idea is clicking a location on the map and loading weather data from that location. My problem is that I cant get the position data from the marker inside of weather.js

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is to think about the problem less as your 'other file' accessing the coordinates, and more as *notifying* your other module that a mouse click on the map has occurred by means of a callback.

Eg. In `weather.js`

```
function handleCoords(latlng){
   //...Do whatever you want with latlng
}

// Export function as needed if you're using modules/webpack.
// (don't worry if you don't know what this means)
```

Then in your `main.js` in your embedded HTML embedded JS

```
// import {handleCoords} from './weather'
// Again ignore this if you're not using modules/don't know what this means.

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
    handleCoords(event.latLng); // This is how you pass the latlng 
                                       // along to weather.js 

});
```